# Java swing - Keyboard input does not work on windows

Tags: java, swing

I am making an RPG game in Java using my Swing-based engine, and everything works on my FreeBSD as well on Linux, but on Windows it seems like the keyboard handler is broken. I have no idea why it happens, the same JAR file works good on Linux/BSD.

I have no source why does this not work as no error popups in the console and everything runs as expected except for the key input.

The game is too large to provide source scraps here (I have no idea what is wrong), but it is on my git: http://codeberg.org/glowiak/gnengine

Package com.glowiak.gnengine contains the engine, com.glowiak.myrpg contains the game and that's all worth noting.

I tried switching JREs but nothing did fix it, on Linux OpenJDK ran it fine, on Windows it did not.

Comment: Please add more detail. At least show how KeyboardHandler is used in the game so we do not have to search it all. Does that mean KeyboardHandler.keyTyped and KeyboardHandler.keyPressed are never invoked? Did you debug it with some console logging or something?

Comment: You have to make sure the right component has the focus, the events are only generated for the components that have focus, I think.

Answer (score 1):

On windows, if you click the game window, then press the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key, the controls then work. This is because when you press the the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key, you are setting the focus onto your JPanel, which is required for a Key Listener to work properly in java swing. For more details, see [this answer by hovercraft full of eels](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27208873/9313980).

My recommendation would be to follow the advice of that answer, and instead of using KeyListeners use KeyBindings.